# checkItem() accept 2 parameters : parameter 1 is an item of a groceryItem array(a string), parameter 2 is the badFood array. is my code correct

Tags: javascript, arrays

`function checkItem( groceryItems['i'], badfoods);`

This is how I defined the function but I am not sure if it is correct.

The two arrays groceryItems[ ] and badFoods[ ] have already been defined by my professor and they are empty. It is a requirement that the function checkItem( ) should accept 2 parameters: 1 which is a single item of groceryItems and 2 which is the array badFoods.

Comment: no, it is not correct. The arguments of a function shouldn't be accessing properties etc. they should just define the identifiers for the parameters passed into the function when it is called

Answer (score 0):

The function definition doesn't need the index

```
function checkItem( groceryItem, badfoods)
{
 //Your code goes here
}
```

Invoking the function should be as below

```
checkItem( groceryItems[i], badfoods);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define only parameter names in function and use it in your business.
And I think badFoods should not be a parameter.
Take a look at following I think it can works for you:

```js
let badFoods = ['badFood', 'badFood2'];
let groceryItems = ['badFood', 'goodFood', 'veryGoodFood'];

function checkItem(item){
  if(badFoods.findIndex(f=> f==item)>-1){
      return 'bad';
  }
  return 'good';
}

console.log("item 0 is: " + checkItem(groceryItems[0]));
console.log("item 1 is: " + checkItem(groceryItems[1]));
```